# Jquery button() click event doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cant find my mistake.
`alert()` is definitely working, but not inside `$('#submit1').click` function...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit1').click(function(){
        alert("JQuery Running!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Jquery Basic</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a>JQuery Test Page</a><br>
        <input id="#submit1" type="button" value="Submit"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not supposed to put the `#` in the html, only in the jquery selector.
So just change

```
<input id="#submit1" type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

to

```
<input id="submit1" type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

---

## Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit1').click(function(){
        alert("JQuery Running!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Jquery Basic</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a>JQuery Test Page</a><br>
        <input id="submit1" type="button" value="Submit"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You missed one more edit "supposed to put the # int he html"

Answer (score 0):

"#submit1" should be "submit1" in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

The `#` indicates you are refering to an `id`. The `id` itself does not need a hash. You should have a look into basic css selectors.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit1').click(function(){
        alert("JQuery Running!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Jquery Basic</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a>JQuery Test Page</a><br>
        <input id="submit1" type="button" value="Submit"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input id="submit1" type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

remove the # in submit1 (id attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Just Changes below input Text in your html...

```
<input id="submit1" type="button" value="Submit"/>
```